# NSLocalizedString returns first parameter that I gave it?

Tags: ios

Anybody know why my localized strings are being ignored?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Files `Settings.bundle/XX.lproj/Root.strings` are used only in Settings.bundle. 
If you would like to use `NSLocalizedString` function, add to project empty .string file, name it Localizable.strings, and make localizable.
This file is used by `NSLocalizedString` function.